# How to merge the duplicate records

Tags: sql

How to merge the duplicate records in single rows.

[image]

Comment: There are no duplicates there. All _rows_ are distinct. BTW, most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear how you are defining a "duplicate" in this case. None of the rows contain identical data. You would need to clarify the rules you are hoping to implement.

Answer (score 0):

from the image output it seems you need just null checking for getting your output

```
select t.* from table_name t
where t.DB_NPI is not null
```

But your question need more clarification with proper text data not image